# Change url in address bar via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I want to change my URLs in my website. I have tried some stuff after going through articles but no help.

What I want is displayed below:
Original Url: `abc.com/en/test/index/abc`
User written Url: `abc.com/en/abc`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I was trying this 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /mycompanies/index/$1 [nc]
But got to know this rule is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Codeigniter ,Just use the [URI Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

```
$route['blog/joe'] = "blogs/users/34";
```

A URL containing the word "journals" in the first segment will be remapped to the "blogs" class

Just place the bellow line in to your application\config\routes.php file end of the line

```
$route['en/abc'] = "en/test/index/abc";
```

It can be work fine :) :) :) :) :) :)

More details visits   https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html